# How to rename object in its own event procedure

Tags: vba, events, rename, renaming

Let's say I have this kind of procedure:

```
Private Sub SomeControl_Click()
    SomeControl.Name = "NewNameControl"
End Sub
```

This one is working fine.

However when I do this:

```
Private Sub SomeControl_Click()
    Dim strName As String
    strName = "NewNameControl"
    SomeControl.Name = strName
End Sub
```

It's causing unpredictable behaviour of my macro (sometimes it works and sometimes it crashes application). I guess it has sth to do with GC (?) So... how to rename a control in its own event? :D

Comment: What Control are talking about here?

Comment: It's an graphic object in SCADA system iFIX

Comment: Hm.. I cant reproduce this issue.

Comment: It's might be just an ifix issue:
http://support.ge-ip.com/support/index?page=kbchannel&id=09237d4900112007ff7cf0741d
This is exactly what im talking about

Comment: pretty much yes so it's not an Excel issue